# Connecting to MySQL database with SSH key in CakePHP3

Tags: php, database, ssh, connection, cakephp-3.0

I'm a super rookie developer so be nice!

I have web hosting and database through GoDaddy. It's linked to MySQL Workbench but need it to be linked to my application, where I'm using CakePHP3.

Can someone please help me with how to enter the right host names, usernames etc. when there's an SSH key involved? See the image for the database credentials to help me fill in the blanks below:

```
'Datasources' => [

    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '???',
        'port' => '3306',
        'username' => '???',
        'password' => '???',
        'database' => 'EquineEventFinder',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
```

DB details image - see for db details.

[image: DB details image - see for db details]

Comment: you want to know the host name ? Which host name should be given to the hostname field? right? do you have cpanel?

Comment: Yes using cpanel

Comment: The SSH is what's throwing me - I've tried all combinations of SSH host name, user name and password with the MySQl host name, user name and password and nothing works....